# C# MVC - Regex for integers with a single space or multiple spaces

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc

I have some `regex` that limits an `input` field to integers with spaces:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "This field can not be left empty")]
[RegularExpression(@"^[\d\s]+$", ErrorMessage = "Please enter integers only with spaces")]
public string Numbers { get; set; }
```

I have been testing my app with single spaces, as any other junk typed in is detected via my validation.

However, I have just noticed validation does not pick up upon *multiple* spaces, which is sort of fine as I would like the user to be able to do this as well as *single* spaces, but I get issues with this line of code:

```
List<int> ints = new List<int>();
ints = numbers.TrimEnd().Split(' ').Select(s => int.Parse(s)).OrderBy(i => i).ToList();
```

Which splits all the numbers up, sorts them in ascending order, and puts them into a `List<int>` so it looks as though the `Split` function is accounting for one space only.

I'm not sure what the best solution is.  It may be a case of limiting the `regex` to a *single* space, if so what would this be, or modifying the code above to accept multiple spaces?

Comment: Add `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` to `Split` method.

Comment: If you don't want to allow empty spaces only or mulitple you could use `^\d+(?: \d+)*$`

Comment: Use `.Split(new[] {" "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)` instead of `.Split(' ')`. You do not have to restrict from entering one or more spaces. However, it makes sense to change the regex to `^[0-9 ]+$` or even `[0-9 ]+` since the entire input should match the regex.

Comment: I tried adding `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` to `Split` method and I get this error: `cannot convert from System.StringSplitOptions to char`

Comment: See my comment above

Comment: Thanks, after experimenting, your `.Split(new[] {" "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)` works well, but the `^[0-9 ]+$` does not fail validation when I type multiple spaces between the numbers, so I might stick with the first option for now, which is a bit more flexible if someone by mistake hits the space bar twice by mistake.

Comment: No, if you want to disallow multiple spaces between the numbers you need `^ *[0-9]+(?: [0-9]+)* *$` (considering there may be any amount of spaces at the start/end).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to let users enter any amount of *spaces* anywhere in the string, you should consider changing `\s` with a space in the regex, or instead of a `String.Split()` use `Regex.Split` with `\s+` pattern, to stay consistent with the input data, or plainly use regex to extract digit chunks with `\d+`.

So, use either

```
[RegularExpression(@"^[\d ]+$", ErrorMessage = "Please enter integers only with spaces")]
// ...
ints = numbers.TrimEnd().Split(new[] {" "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(s => int.Parse(s)).OrderBy(i => i).ToList();
```

Or keep the same regex as you have and grab all numbers with a regex:

```
ints = Regex.Matches(numbers, @"\d+").Cast<Match>().Select(s => int.Parse(s)).OrderBy(i => i).ToList();
```

If you plan to forbid entering more than 1 space between the numbers use either of

```
^ *[0-9]+(?: [0-9]+)* *$
^\s*\d+(?:\s\d+)*\s*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rEkAKc/1).